# C# public only for classes of the same interface

Tags: c#, interface, private

Can I make some properties public only to same interface classes and readonly to all other classes?

Comment: This requirement becomes a prime candidate for an abstract class in place of the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use explicit implementation, for example:

```
interface IFoo {
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo {
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    int IFoo.Value {
        get { return Value; }
        set { Value = value; }
    }
}
```

When accessed via `Foo` only the get will be accessible; when accessed via `IFoo` both getter and setter will be accessible.

Any use?

Comment: Not quite what I thought the OP meant.. but nice!

Comment: Indeed. Also, you have a typo (type-o... pun). `into`.. instead of `int`.

Comment: Nevermind.. just realised I can fix that sort of thing up on people's answers... hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 0):

An interface is just something like a contract for classes. It doesn't change the accessibility level.

If a member of a class is public it is public to all classes that can access the class. The only restrictions you can have is the use of `internal` or `protected`. `internal` makes the member public to classes which are defined within the same assembly and `protected` makes it public to classes derived from the class.

Instead of the interface you can create an abstract base class and make the members protected:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public abstract class FooBase : IFoo
{
    public abstract int Value { get; set; }

    protected void ProtectedMethod()
    {
    }
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

However you can not define a member that is accessible by classes that implement a specific interface. There is no access modifier like `public-to-IFoo-otherwise-private`.